# change dynamically added button background from another function

Tags: android

I dinamically add some buttons to my TableL like this

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById( R.id.tableLayout1 );
   Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ myPrefLocalMedia + mat_foto);

   final ImageButton b = new ImageButton(this);
   b.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
   b.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
   b.setImageBitmap(bmp);
   b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
         ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SuperlineaActivity.this);
         progressDialog.setMessage("Realizando el pedido...");
         progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
         b.setPressed(true);
         if ( (miPedido == null) || ( miPedido.isEnproceso()==false) ) {
            Log.e("log_","Hago post! Creo pedido!!");
            Hacerpost eginpost = new Hacerpost(SuperlineaActivity.this, progressDialog);
            eginpost.execute(myPrefApiPeticionMaterial,mat_id, PUESTOID, LINEAID, USUARIOID, PRODUCTOID);
         } else {
            Hacerput puttask = new Hacerput(SuperlineaActivity.this, progressDialog);
            puttask.execute(myPrefApiPeticionMaterial,miPedido.getId());
         }
      }
   });

row.addView( b, 300,300 );
```

When it is pressed it performs some AsyncTask (HttpPost) and it returns one color code. I need to change the pressed background color with that color code but how do I know witch button I clicked?

This is the function where I receive the HttpPost data:

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public void erantzuna(JSONObject myJson) {
        if ( miPedido == null ) {
            AlertDialog alerta   = new AlertDialog.Builder(SuperlineaActivity.this).create();
            alerta.setTitle("PEDIDO EN PROCESO");
            alerta.setMessage("El pedido se a procesado. Espera.");
            alerta.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            alerta.show();
            String kolorea = null;
            String pedidoid = null;
            try {
                kolorea = myJson.getString("kolorea");
                pedidoid = myJson.getString("pedidoid");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.e("log_", "Bueltan da: => " + kolorea);
            Log.e("log_", "Bueltan da: => " + pedidoid);
            miPedido = new Pedido(pedidoid, kolorea);


            try {
                if (miPedido.getKolorea().equals("kuadro-gorria")) {
                  //
                  // Here I need to change the pressed ImageButton color to RED
                  //
                } elseif ( miPedido.getKolorea().equals("kuadro-urdina")) {
                  //
                  // Here I need to change the pressed ImageButton color to BLUE
                  //
                } else {
                  //
                  // Here I need to change the pressed ImageButton color to transparent
                  //
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_","Boton Color => " + e.toString());
            }


        } else {
            miPedido = null;
        }
    }
```

Any help or clue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should manage your dynamically added buttons, like put them into a list, or, if you won't need a reference for them later, just give the Button to the asyncTask (like in the constructor or something) and change its color in the onPostExecute method of the asynctask. But don't forget to prepare for cases like the Activity gets destroyed while the task waits for the response, as in that case the Button will no longer exist, and this could cause memory leaks as well.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer but I can not send the button to the AsyncTask because I have too much logic there. I´m working on the list solution, but I don´t know how to get clicked button to change the background color

Comment: Ok, I got it! Thanks for the clue! The list approach works ;)